# Starting a custom window in wpf from code behind does not draw it's content

Tags: c#, wpf, window

In my tests, I've created a simple class like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;

namespace Test
{
    public class MyCustomWindow: Window
    {

    }
}
```

This class is compiled into a dll. 
In another project, I tried to use this custom window, like this:

```
<Custom:MyCustomWindow x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Custom="clr-namespace:Test;assembly=Test"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="1210" WindowState="Maximized" >

   <Grid Background="Blue">
       <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="457,212,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/> 
   </Grid>
```

This thing compiles with no errors, and works great when the custom window is opened by the "StartupUri" in the App.xaml file (that defines the first window loaded).

However, if I set other window to load in the StartupUri, and:

```
MainWindow m = new MainWindow();
m.Activate();
m.Show();
this.Close();
```

The CustomWindow will open, but without any content, without button and without the blue grid - and even without the title.

Any workaround? And what I need to do to open a Window with the same behavior of the StartupUri?

**Edit:**

I've noticed that the MainWindow (or any window derived from MyCustomWindow) simply cannot have the method InitializeComponent() in the constructor, because it does not exist in the context. Strangely, when using StartupUri, the contents are loaded normally without this.

**Edit 2:**

I think that the problem is occurring because I can't put the InitializeComponent() method in the MyCustomWindow. This explains why the MainWindow can be loaded normally into the StartupUri: it's loading directly from the xaml file, so it's parsing the content without the need of the InitializeComponent.

I starting to think about implement the IComponentConnector interface, but I have no idea how to do this.

**Edit 3:**

The code-behind of the file MainWindow.xaml.cs is:

```
using Test;

namespace TestingCustomWindow
{
    public partial class MainWindow : MyCustomWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
              // Cannot use InitializeComponent here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mhmmm, you dont open the **MyCustomWindow**, instead you open the MainWindow with the code: **MainWindow** m = new MainWindow() ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yep, I'm opening the MainWindow, because it's the name of the C# class that xaml is referencing. If I open a "new" MyCustomWindow, I will not open the Window that have a button, right?

Comment: I want to open the specific MainWindow that inherit from MyCustomWindow.

Comment: Uh, I see. I have never used before another classname for code behind. It doesn't feel good for me... But did you try to open the the Window with MyCustomWindow m = new MyCustomWindow()?

Comment: Same behaviour: a blank window without title. I will update the question with more information.

Comment: i tried this and it worked for me. you need to keep StarupURi blank if you are doing this in OnStartup override MainWindow m = new MainWindow();
m.Activate();
m.Show();
this.Close();

Comment: mmm, I need to open a window before the mainwindow (splashscreen). In App.xaml, the StartupUri is referencing the splash.xaml, and into the splash.xaml.cs, I have an event that have the code to open the MainWindow. Doing exactly this does not work, at least for me.

Comment: Dont know bro,but i tried the same thing . Set the starupuri to one window and on some event (say buttonclick) I created the Mainwindow and close the first window. I works for me

Comment: You have the InitializeComponent() method in any place? I get an error when I put it, in the "public class MyCustomWindow: Window" constructor, or in the "public class MainWindow : MyCustomWindow constructor, because I'm not inheriting from IComponentConnector

Comment: No i dont have initialize component in the class derived from Window. Actually I dont think that is needed.  InitializeComponent method exists in a corresponding .g.cs file that is automatically generated. Since your MyCustomWindow dont have xaml to load it does not need initialize component

Comment: @nit yep, but what about MainWindow? it have a xaml, with a grid and a a button. Without the InitializeComponent, it will never load the content.

Comment: but your MainWindow has xaml right and it is a partial class and also the code behind?..

Comment: pls add the new window using Visual Studio and Replace :Window with :MyCustomWindow. You will get initializecomponent

Comment: WOW! It's work! What was the error in the other window? I'm confused.... Bug in VS?

Comment: No thats not the bug in VS...thats how VS help to generate the partial class and define initializecomponent in it. In your case if not leveraging VS, and adding xaml nd codebehind manually you will have to write initializecomponent by urself...

Comment: @nit The problem is that my code wasn't compiling with InitializeComponent() until I added a new Window. Don't know why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pls add the new window using Visual Studio and 
Replace :Window with :MyCustomWindow. You will get initializecomponent. You will hav to update window tag with your CustumWindow tag in xaml also

Adding it as answer so other can use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the constructor has to look like this

```
public class MyCustomWindow: Window
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: error: "The name InitializeComponent does not exist in current context"

Comment: If MainWindow has MainWindow.xaml you should be able to use InitializeComponent() in my opinion.

Comment: You are correct. I included another window in the project, like nit said, and it now works. I think that maybe a intelisense bug.